# Try-with-resources when calling super constructor

Tags: java, java-8, try-with-resources

Is there any good way of using try-with-resources when opening an `InputStream` in a constructor and then passing that to a super constructor?

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
public class A {
    public A(InputStream stream) {
        // Do something with the stream but don't close it since we didn't open it
    }
}

public class B {
    public B(File file) {
        // We open the stream so we need to ensure it's properly closed
        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            super(new FileInputStream(file));
        }
    }
}
```

But, of course, since `super` must be the first statement in the constructor this isn't allowed. Is there any good way of achieving this?

Comment: I would have the caller provide the input stream to `public B(InputStream in)` and close it too. No reason to make the derived class less versatile than the base class.

Comment: More versatile, but also more cumbersome to use. I could support both, but not having the `B(File file)` constructor is not an option.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem comes from consuming the stream inside A's constructor. If it wasn't the case, you would simply store the stream in an instance variable and make A `AutoClosable`.

Comment: @DidierL: That wouldn't work because then I couldn't use the instance of `B` outside the scope of the try-with-resources.

Comment: Then having a separate initializer would be a better solution, or you should [_favor composition over inheritance_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Can we assume that A consumes the file entirely in its constructor, so that it does not need to stay open after B's constructor finishes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider using a static factory method instead of using the constructor directly. Make at least `B`'s constructor private, and create a method such as

```
private B(InputStream is) {
    super(is);
    // Whatever else is needed
}

public static B newInstance(File file) {
    B result;
    try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        result = new B(stream);
    }
    // Further processing
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go :

```
public class A {
    protected A(){
        // so he can't be called from the outside, subclass ensure that init is done properly.
    }

    public A(InputStream stream) {
        init(stream);
    }
    // not be able to call it from outside
    protected final init(InputStream is){
        //here goes the code
    }
}

public class B {
    public B(File file) {
        // We open the stream so we need to ensure it's properly closed
        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            init(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm posting this here as a possible answer, however here i'm consdering :

1. You can update A's code
2. You're moving constructor's code to an init method, thanks to protected empty arg constructor, only subclasses have to handle the call to init properly. Some may see that as not so well designed. My point is as soon your subclassing something, you have to know more about it that just when you just using it.

Comment: As you said it requires access to *A*'s source code and it won't work if there are final variables in *A* that needs to be initialized from contents in the stream.

Comment: you should make `init` `final`, as otherwise a subclass could override it and break the constructor of `A`. I think that is called constructor leak or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly I do not have a compiler on hand to test on but could you not do as follows.

```
public class B {
    private static InputStream file2stream(File f){
        // We open the stream so we need to ensure it's properly closed
        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            return stream;
        }catch(/*what you need to catch*/){
             //cleanup
             // possibly throw runtime exception
        }
    }
    public B(File file) {
        super(file2stream(file))
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the end of the `try` block is reached before the end of `file2stream`, closing the file before it can be passed into `super`.

Comment: I might have missunderstod the question, but I thought that was the point. I understod the question such that the only thing that was suposed to be protected by try was the construction of the InputStream, if that is not the case how shoud it be understood?

Comment: You didn't understand Hank D's comment, I think. The problem is that in try-with-resources, the resource (stream) that was opened is closed at the end of the block. The `return` statement doesn't prevent this (or there would not be a point to the `try`). So when `file2stream` returns the resource, it is **already closed**. Also note the difference between *try-with-resources* (which is done to close resources) and *try-catch* which is done to catch exceptions and is not the one discussed here.

Comment: Ahh, that was my problem, yup that is a problem.